# URL problem on IIS, using PHP

Tags: php, iis

I've developed an application, using LAMP, and everything works fine, after migrating over to IIS, some pages don't work correctly.
I have a service_edit.php, which carries over URL parameters from the previous page, e.g.:
*service_edit.php?id=5&serv=22*

After updating the record, the following variable should redirect the browser to:

```
$updateGoTo = "freelancer_details.php?id=" . $row_rsFreeLancer['freeid'] . "";
```

But the browser produces a HTTP 500 error with *service_edit.php?id=5&serv=22* in the address bar.

If I use:

```
$updateGoTo = "freelancer_list.php;
```

Everything works fine.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or if there is a setting in IIS to get this to work?

---

**EDIT**

OK, getting a bit closer to the problem now...

I've found that on my LAMP server, after the record has been updated, the page goes back to the freelancer_details.php page, with the correct details displayed, however, the parameters from the previous page are carried over too.

The URL, instead of displaying:

```
freelancer_details.php?id=5
```

displays:

```
freelancer_details.php?id=&id=5&serv=22
```

How do I remove the URL parameters from the previous page, so the URL displays correctly, and therefore work on the IIS server?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say specifically what the problem is from what you have here (it's hard to understand what you're saying without seeing the rest of the script), but I can almost guarantee that IIS isn't the problem.  Most likely there is some confusion with the page you are trying to forward to - either it's not there, or not being forwarded properly.

Try doing this:

```
$updateGoTo = "freelancer_details.php?id=" . $row_rsFreeLancer['freeid'] . "";
echo("<a href='".$updateGoTo."'>Click Me</a>");
```

and try clicking.  That will tell you if there is truly a page at that URL, or if it's off.

Also, how are you forwarding to the next page?  Are you using header() or something else?

**Edit**

Hi,

What this means ?id=&id=5 is that instead of having $_GET['id'] available as 5, it will be an array with two values, one of which will be blank, and the other will be 5.

You need to figure out why the id is being added twice and fix that.  Without code, I can't tell you much else.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've just noticed on my LAMP server, that after updating the record, which should go to:
freelance_details.php?id=5
it actually goes to:
freelancer_details.php?id=&id=5&serv=20
although it does display the correct page, the URL is incorrect. would this URL stop IIS?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a DEV box, go in the IIS and/or IE and remove the "Friendly http error" that way, you should get a more verbose error message.